# How to print to file?

Tags: c++, arrays, filestream

I'm need to print some info on a file ".txt".

I wrote on the program the link of the file I want to copy the info. The ".txt" file is empty.

Eclipse tells me that the code is without error. This is the part of code of the print on file:

```
void stampaVendute(string& vendute,int& n,Opere f[],char p[],int a){
    cout<<"\nInserisci il file sul quale vuoi visualizzare le opere vendute: "<<endl;
        getline(cin,vendute);

        ofstream ofs;
        ofs.open(vendute.c_str());
        if(!ofs.good()){
                cout<<"C'è qualche problema nell'apertura del file"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if((!stricmp(p,f[i].N_C)) and a<=f[i].anno){
            ofs<<"\nOPERA "<<(i+1)<<endl;
            ofs<<"Codice: "<<f[i].codice<<";"<<endl;
            ofs<<"Titolo: "<<f[i].titolo<<";"<<endl;
            ofs<<"Autore: "<<f[i].N_C<<";"<<endl;
            ofs<<"Anno: "<<f[i].anno<<";"<<endl;
            ofs<<"Valore: "<<f[i].prezzo<<";"<<endl;
        }
        ofs.close();
    }
    cout<<"\nI DATI SONO STATI COPIATI CORRETTAMENTE SUL FILE!"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you entering full or relative path? Also, `ofstream`'s `open` can take in a `std::string`, so not sure why you're using `.c_str()` there.

Comment: no this isnt enough to know what is wrong. For example, what is `n` ? When it is `0` then nothing being written to the file is to be expected. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: Did you try to debug the program?

Comment: <O/T> nit, no reason to pass `n` by reference here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `if((!stricmp(p,f[i].N_C)) and a<=f[i].anno){`  fails the test then nothing is printed to the file.  Add a line that unconditionally prints to the file after opening, to see if it works.

Print the file name to the user when the file is opened successfully.

If you are using Windows, you can use *process monitor* from SysInternals (now owned by Microsoft) to see what file is actually being opened.

---

`ofs.open(vendute.c_str());`
why are you using `c_str` here?  You know that `open` takes a `std::string` normally!  You are getting a pointer to the raw characters just to construct a new different string object, and forcing the compiler to re-count the number of characters (calling `strlen()` again).

You should write it as one line anyway.  Initialize the variable when you define it:

```
ofstream ofs {vendute};
```

---

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

---

```
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ... many uses of `f[i]` follows
```

You should be using a range-based `for` loop rather than subscripts, but the way you are passing the data (separate pointer to the first element and length) instead of simply passing a collection prevents that.  This is not a good way to do things!  See Standard Guidelines [⧺I.13](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-array) etc.

If you did *need* to go over the collection via subscripts, don't keep subscripting it over and over and over.  Make a reference variable pointing to that spot:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   const auto& x = f[i];
   ... now use x over and over, not f[i]
```

---

## here's your problem

Look where `ofs.close();` is being called.  The indentation of the code in the post is all messed up... it looks like this should be after the loop, before the final `cout` line.  But what's that extra `}` coming from?

You are closing the file after the first iteration through the loop.  If that case (`i==0`) did not print results, nothing will ever be shown.